# Creating an offline Webpage for Visitors registration

Tags: html, css, database, offline

First question here for me and I hope to get everything right.

I want to create an offline website for visitors to my company fair booth.
We will have no internet connection at the booth and I would like to have something fancy with HTML / CSS but everything will run offline.

Here's my question, which technology you suggest to use for an offline database to store the data directly on the PC used for registrations?

The point is that once we're back in our county we'll retrieve from the file that will be created all the contacts we'll gather at the booth.

Keep in mind that there will be no techy person at the booth so I need something that I'll implement and run automatically so they'll just power up the PC and are ready to go.

Thanks in advance for any kind answer.

Regards.

Comment: In your scenario, a web application will add way too much overhead - just create a small MS Access App for data entry - or even only a MS Excel form.

Comment: Recommendation questions are off-topic. (But you can just use whatever you would use if you had an Internet connection, but installed locally).